# how to get user input in Scilab

Tags: signals, scilab

How to get user input in GUI in Scilab? 
I want to use the user input to calculate it as graph.
I have tried searching but not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a look at the input; x_dialog functions
You can also define more sophisticated dialog with the uicontrol tool